# How to prevent value of javafx ComboBox from being modified?

Tags: javafx-8

I want the user to set the value by selecting an item from the ComboBox  drop-down list. Once a value is assigned, thereafter he must not be able to modify it.

Comment: another option (than disabling, as suggested in the answer) is to remove all other items from the list. Whichever you choose, be aware that users tend to get confused and irritated quite quickly - what if they accidentally had chosen a value and wanted to undo the choice?

Answer (score 2):

Would something simple like this suffice?

```
ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
comboBox.getItems().add("Item 1");
comboBox.getItems().add("Item 2");
comboBox.valueProperty().addListener((e) -> {
    comboBox.setDisable(true);
});
```

This will disable the ComboBox upon the user selecting a value. You could even override the CSS to make the combobox appear as normal.

Comment: why would you want to confuse your users ;-)